# How do I fix my error with test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I need to cover some new functionality with tests, and for this I need to convert the lead in the test. I have two sandboxes (one is where we are developing; the second is for testing). In the first, everything is OK - the test passes and covers my new functionality. And on the second - an error, the test does not pass:

> Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts.

I have done a lot of manipulations in order to try to figure out where the callout occurs, but to no avail. Please advise me how I can identify the callout?

method for covering

```java
public void fillingAddressForCustomer(List<Lead> newLeads, List<Lead> oldLeads) {
    Set<Id> accountsId = new Set<Id>();
    for(Integer i = 0, s = Trigger.new.size(); i < s; i++) {
        if(!oldLeads[i].isConverted && newLeads[i].isConverted) {
            accountsId.add(newLeads[i].convertedAccountId);
        }
    } if(accountsId.size() > 0) {
        Map<Id, Account> mapAccounts = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT BillingAddress, BillingCity, BillingCountry, BillingPostalCode, BillingState, BillingStreet, ShippingAddress
                                                            FROM Account
                                                            WHERE ID =:accountsId]);
        List<Account> accountsForUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for (Lead l : newLeads) {
            Account tempAcc = mapAccounts.get(l.convertedAccountId);
            if((l.City != null 
                || l.Country != null
                || l.PostalCode != null
                || l.State != null
                || l.Street != null)
                && tempAcc.BillingAddress != null
                && (tempAcc.BillingCity != l.City
                || tempAcc.BillingCountry != l.Country
                || tempAcc.BillingPostalCode != l.PostalCode
                || tempAcc.BillingState != l.State
                || tempAcc.BillingStreet != l.Street)) {
                tempAcc.ShippingCity = l.City; 
                tempAcc.ShippingCountry = l.Country;
                tempAcc.ShippingPostalCode = l.PostalCode;
                tempAcc.ShippingState = l.State;
                tempAcc.ShippingStreet = l.Street;
                accountsForUpdate.add(tempAcc);
            }
        }
        if (accountsForUpdate.size() > 0) {
            update accountsForUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

test method

```java
@isTest private static void testFillingAddressForCustomer() {
    
    Account testAccount = TestFactory.createAccount('Test Account');
    testAccount.Was_Lead__c = false;
    testAccount.BillingCountry = 'Country';
    testAccount.BillingCity = 'City';
    testAccount.BillingPostalCode = 'Postal Code';
    testAccount.BillingState = 'State';
    testAccount.BillingStreet = 'Street';
    insert testAccount;

    Lead testLead = new Lead(Email = 'test@gmail.com',
                             LastName = 'Test',
                             Country = 'Lead Country',
                             City = 'Lead City',
                             PostalCode = 'Lead Postal Code',
                             State = 'Lead State',
                             Street = 'Lead Street');
    insert testLead;

    test.startTest();
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
    lc.setAccountId(testAccount.Id);
    lc.setLeadId(testLead.id);
    lc.setConvertedStatus('Closed - Converted');

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
    test.stopTest();

    testAccount = [SELECT ShippingAddress FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ID =: lcr.getAccountId() LIMIT 1];
    System.assertNotEquals(testAccount.ShippingAddress, null);
}
```

[image]

Comment: My assumption from what I've seen so far is there is likely a Lead trigger that is making the web callout. You will need to find that (use your debug log) and create an HttpCalloutMock for your tests. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Answer (score 0):

Run your test from the Developer Console (in Salesforce), and you'll get a log file in the Logs tab. Open that, and you should see exactly which line the exception is thrown from.

### Basic Example

```
@isTest class q363955 {
    @isTest static void test() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com/');
        new Http().send(req);
    }
}
```

You'll then see the log:

[image: Log Tab]

And the log will look something like this:

```
53.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,FINEST;CALLOUT,NONE;DB,FINEST;NBA,NONE;SYSTEM,FINE;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WAVE,NONE;WORKFLOW,FINER
06:48:38.2 (2338783)|EXECUTION_STARTED
06:48:38.2 (2450091)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p1T0000042Spn|q363955.test()
06:48:38.2 (3448028)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[4]|System.HttpRequest.setMethod(String)
06:48:38.2 (3702219)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[4]|System.HttpRequest.setMethod(String)
06:48:38.2 (3944800)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|System.HttpRequest.setEndpoint(String)
06:48:38.2 (4022049)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|System.HttpRequest.setEndpoint(String)
06:48:38.2 (4088844)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[6]|System.Http.send(ANY)
06:48:38.2 (4916328)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[6]|System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts
06:48:38.2 (5036360)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[6]|System.Http.send(ANY)
06:48:38.2 (5240564)|FATAL_ERROR|System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Class.q363955.test: line 6, column 1
06:48:38.2 (5417421)|FATAL_ERROR|System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts
```

Where it says `Class.q363955.test: line 6, column 1` in my example shows that it crashed on line 6 with this error. You can read this information to determine the path (the list will include a full stack trace), so you can easily identify the problem path.

The solution to this problem is to add a callout mock, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm).

Comment: Yes, thank you, I looked at the log file and here it is (added a screenshot), but I didn't understand what I need to fix based on this...

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me that mock won't help. The most important thing I need to set for my Lead record is "isConverted" to "true" and fill in "convertedAccountId". But these fields cannot be changed and I will not be able to create a record based on the JSON received from mock. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @uniqueuser sounds like you have a trigger with asynchronous code that makes a callout. Try using a callout mock and you should be able to identity the source.

Comment: Yes, logically it happens somewhere. I have a lot of logic for different objects trigger calls. And the code was written before me. But so far the search does not give anything.  I will continue.

Answer (score 0):

The two fields isConverted and convertedAccountId are set by Lead Conversion. In Apex, that is be done with the method Database.convertLead . As you observed, your code cannot set the fields; but convertLead() can .
You code you are testing probably has that call, but execution isn't getting to that point because the forbidden-in-testing callout occurs first. You need a mock callout, as sfdcfox posted. The code you are testing must avoid doing the real callout during tests. It should be coded with if (! Test.isRunningTest())   .
To find the right place to make that change, use the Developer Console, as sfdcfox posted.